# std::promise in realtime context

Tags: c++11, promise, c++14, real-time

I am developing an application with a realtime context.

One of the threads that executes in realtime context dequeues `Task` message objects from a mailbox (with real-time capabilities). Those `Task` messages contain a `std::promise` and a `command`.

After the thread gets the `Task` it executes the command and after that, `std::promise::set_value()` will be called.

Because of that, I am concerned that calling `std::promise::set_value()` might not have real-time capability.

Does anybody knows if `set::value()` internally allocates heap storage or does something else that would break the real-time capability?

Here is some snipplet to hopefully make my question clearer:

```
void RealTimeThread::exec()
{
  while( active_ ) {
    Task receivedTask;

    if( mailbox_.getMailTimed( receivedTask, std::chrono::milliseconds( 100 ) ) ) {
      try {
        if( receivedTask.cmd ) {
          receivedTask.cmd->execute();
        } else {
          // TODO: some internal actions on timeout
          throw std::runtime_error{"Command invalid"};
        }

        // does the following call has real-time capabilities?
        receivedTask.cmdPromise.set_value();
      } catch( ... ) {
        receivedTask.cmdPromise.set_exception( std::current_exception() );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Aside: you seem to be replicating [packaged_task](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task)

Comment: Thank you, that was new to me.

Comment: It's too bad that nobody can help me :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anybody is interested:

A `std::promise` can be constructed given a allocator. This is used to allocated the "shared state" which is used on the `std::future` objects.

If you can provide an `allocator` that allocated on realtime (deterministic) it is fine to use `std::promise` in such context.
Such an `allocator` is motley allocating from a memory block that was allocated before application entered realtime context.